# Trickle charge or maintaing charge with drone motor?

Tags: batteries, charging, charge, drone

I'm wondering if there is anyway to make a drone self charge while flying it without losing much performance? I know this could not work to completely charge but even if some type of trickle charge or maintenance charge to prolong flight time. I'm very knowledgeable about a lot of things electrical engineering is not one of those things. So I leave this to anybody with any knowledge or experience with this type of scenario. Now I get that so much energy is lost in the process of using energy. Hence the reason you can't make a everlasting generator that makes power. You see all these gimmick type of videos on you tube where they showing perpetual motion. Still I wonder if there was a way to do some type of charge or help with using the motion of drone to spin some type of wheel like a turning or something to create some energy. I have a feeling the possibility is small but I thought I would ask. Thanks and be kind as I said this is just an  of mine since I want to be able to fly drone longer.

Comment: this is called regeneration, what EV do. a copter drone probably would be very inefficient, but a horizontal flying ones probably could dive and recharge. In fact it usually doesn't even require anything special, only a motor velocity control- the energy will flow back to the battery.

Comment: "... probably could dive and recharge ..." isn't going to work. It will take more energy to get back to the original altitude than was generated in the dive. Any regeneration system will increase drag on the aircraft. "You can't win. You can't even break even!" Forget it.

Comment: regeneration works on scooters and EVs because those are heavy things that need brakes. A drone is light and has no brakes; it needs all it's power to fight gravity, and that power is spent at ~100% efficiency compared to a recovery means which would be 50% at best, so it would be twice as beneficial to just park it on the ground.